# ReactJS: Trigger event from child in parent component

Tags: reactjs

i have two components: 1.Parent  2.Child
there is an event in child component called onChange() which return a value.
i want to receive the value which was returned from OnChange() in componentDidMount() in parent component.

Example:

```
class Parent extends PureComponent {
componentDidMount() {
 let value = CHILD.onChange(); //triggered when ever onChange() 
}
 render(){
      return(
        <Child />
)
  }
}
const Child = () => {

  const onChange = () => {
    const value = 1
    return value;
  };
}
```

Comment: You need to define the `onChange()` method in your Parent and then pass it as a `prop` in your Child component and execute it there. The value can be saved in the state of the Parent component.

Comment: You should define the onChange handler on the Parent component and pass over it to the Child component as a prop.
In the child component, you receive the handler and set it to the appropriate event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Parent extends PureComponent {


handleChildChange = value => {
 //Do your stuff with value, pass it to the state and take it from there if you like
}


 render(){
      return(
        <Child handleChange={this.handleChildChange} />
)
  }
}
const Child = (props) => {

  const onChange = () => {
    value = 1
    props.handleChange(value);
    }
  };
}
```